# How to create HTML format email in CQ5?

Tags: html-email, aem, dam

Currently I am able to send plain text email from CQ without using OOTB mail service.

Now I need to send email in html format. The email template should allow author to edit the content like adding images from DAM and also adding components from sidekick.

I am able to send html email but the image is not rendered in the mail I receive.

I am new to CQ, so any guidance on this will be really helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you adding the HTML? is the HTML generated for the email dynamic ? Does that come from a component ?

Comment: HTML is generated dynamically by author.. he can add components in the html page too

Answer (score 0):

When the HTML is generated for the page it refers to the image using html tag img src="/content/dam/path" and hence visible on the page. But when you receive those email your images point to the CQ Dam path this is wrong and since its not referenced you loose the images in the email. This does works if the image is been referred completely e.g. if you refer to the image src https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/73314c7d617f62490c828a976282e622?s=24&d=identicon&r=PG it does work. In summary check the image src.